# Open a file and make it a variable

Tags: php

Lets say I have a file called doc.txt. And in it lets say we have in it: `a line here!`. I want to make a variable that insides the stuff writes in doc.txt. How can I do that??

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp

Comment: thanks Anant, that was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **[file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)**.

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('doc.txt');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

And try to use google, I'm sure you would find this if you at least tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("doc.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fgets($myfile);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: thanks, but I did like this: `$stuff = fgets($file);`

Comment: @Doruk Ayar unless you correctly open and close it, you are doing it wrong. If you want to to id with one line if code, that's what file_get_contents is for.